# Custom IDs with AWS API Gateway and DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I followed [this tutorial](https://itnext.io/setting-up-api-gateway-with-dynamodb-using-cloudformation-a8ab3e70f494) to connect AWS API Gateway and DynamoDB. My DynamoDB table is defined as follows:

```
Resources:
  DragonsTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      TableName: mytable
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: id
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: id
          KeyType: HASH
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: 1
        WriteCapacityUnits: 1
```

I was hoping to be able to use my own custom `id` values, but when I include one in the POST request this is overridden and replaced with a UUID. Is there any way I can use my own IDs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DynamoDB does not auto generate IDs for you.

You are setting your mapping template to use the context requestId as shown in the tutorial:

`"id": "S": "$context.requestId"`

You should set this template mapping to the Id you wish to use in your openAPI mapping.